# Python: Maximum recursion depth exceeded when printing custom exception

Tags: python, recursion, custom-exceptions, repr

The following code throws `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object`.  I can resolve the infinite recursion in two different ways, but I don't understand why each fix works and thus don't know which to use, or if either are correct.

```
class FileError( Exception ):
    def __init__( self, filename=None, *a, **k ):
        #Fix 1: remove super
        super( FileError, self ).__init__( self, *a, **k )
        self.filename = filename
    def __repr__( self ):
        return "<{0} ({1})>".format( self.__class__.__name__, self.filename )
    #Fix 2: explicitly define __str__
    #__str__ = __repr__

print( FileError( "abc" ) )
```

If I remove `super`, the code runs but doesn't print anything.  This doesn't make sense since according to this post, [Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python), omitting `__str__` will call `__repr__` but that doesn't seem to be happening here.

If I, instead, keep the call to `super` and add `__str__ = __repr__`, then I get the expected output and there is no recursion.

Can someone explain why the infinite recursion is present, why each change resolves the inifinte recursion, and why one fix might be preferred over the other?

Comment: The reason your `__repr__` isn't being used as the `__str__` is because the base Exception defines `__str__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `super` invocation is wrong: `self` should not be supplied again, it's already injected by `super`. This way, `file_error.args[0] is file_error` because you pass `self` as an extra argument to the exception constructor. This should make it obvious why fix #1 (removing the super call altogether) helps, but of course the best fix is to **pass the right arguments**:

```
super(FileError, self).__init__(filename, *a, **k)
```

The reason for the infinite recursion: First off, only `object.__str__` delegates to `__repr__`; `BaseException` defines both `__str__` and `__repr__` separately, so `str()` of an exception calls that overload, not your `__repr__`. `BaseException.__str__` usually [prints the args tuple](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7ce464ba615a/Objects/exceptions.c#l105) (which would use `repr`), though when it contains a single argument, it prints the `str()` of that single argument.

This invokes `BaseException.__str__` again, and so on. Fix #2 prevents this cycle by not entering `BaseException.__str__` in the first place, instead using your `__repr__` which does not touch the args tuple at all.

Comment: @BleedingFingers Yes, quite likely. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @delnan I marked this as the most correct answer because it answers why the recursion happens and in doing so has an excellent description of how `super()` works. I now see exactly why there was recursion and also understand that I do have to override `__str__`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't pass `self` to `__init__` as the first argument. That's causing the recursion.

It should be:

```
super( FileError, self ).__init__( filename, *a, **k )
```

The recursion is caused because

```
>>> print Exception("Abc")
Abc
```

`Exception` prints the first argument. So when you initialize the base class of `FileError` i.e. `Exception` with `self` which inherits `__str__` from it's parent which prints the first argument (hope you see the recursion in the statement).. hence you get the infinite recursion.

`__str__ = __repr__` overrides the inherited `__str__` and mitigates the infinite recursion.

Comment: How exactly does this cause the recursion? I quickly identified that error myself, but I'm dumbfounded as to how this causes `str` to recursive infinitely while `repr` works fine.

Comment: I think I just figured it out myself. I'm still curious to see your explanation though.

Comment: I think it's because the `self` is being used as the base exceptions `message` parameter. So str is called on `message` which calls `str` which calls `str` on message, etc.

Answer (score 4):

This line is incorrect:

```
super( FileError, self ).__init__( self, *a, **k )
```

You need to pass `self` in `super()` but not again as argument to `__init__`. So it needs to be:

```
super( FileError, self ).__init__( *a, **k )
```