# Declaring Subclass without passing self

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an abstract base class `Bicycle`:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Bicycle(ABC):

    def __init__(self, cadence = 10, gear = 10, speed = 10):
        self._cadence = cadence
        self._gear = gear         
        self._speed = speed

    @abstractmethod
    def ride(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return  "Cadence: {0}  Gear: {1}  Speed: {2}".format(self._cadence, 
                                                             self._gear, self._speed)
```

and a subclass `MountainBike`:

```
from Bicycle import Bicycle

class MountainBike(Bicycle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)


    def ride(self):
        return "Riding my Bike"
```

The following code will cause a [recursion error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392135/python-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-when-printing-custom-exception), but if I remove `self` from the `super().__init__(self)`, the call to `__str__(self):` works.

**Question:**

1. I only discovered this error when I implemented the `__str__(self):`

   In Python 3.x when calling the parent constructor from the child with no arguments, is passing `self`, necessary?
2. Suppose `MountainBike` now sets the `cadence`, `gear`, `speed` this means in my subclass the constructor will look like this:

   ```
   class MountainBike(Bicycle):

       def __init__(self, cadence, gear, speed):
           super().__init__(cadence,gear,speed)
   ```

notice, `self` isn't being passed in the `super` because to my knowledge, it can throw the variable assignments off. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: In python 3 the `self` is not needed as I believe that `super` does that for you, so: `super().__init__()` is sufficient (plus `cadence,gear,speed` as needed in your case).

Comment: So, either way, with or without arguments, passing `self` isn't necessary, correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: According to the official documentation, it is listed as mandatory. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__

Comment: @Attersson - It doesn't say you should pass `self`, it just says that the `super().__init__()` should be called from a subclass which is necessary.

Comment: Right. It is mandatory in the first `__init__` but should be omitted in the `super().__init__()` because it is already implicitly passed there.

Comment: @Attersson - Right!

Comment: Actually it is not even mandatory in the first `__init__` . If you omit it, all the variables used in the init would be local and only exist until the function terminates. It may be appropriate if you don't want to touch the instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is passed implicitly to the super call, so adding it explicitly sends it twice:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(self)
```

That ends up calling `Bicycle(self, self)`, which is the same as `Bicycle(self, cadence=self)`.

Later on, you have probably tried convert your instance to `str` (e.g. to print it), so this was called:

```
def __str__(self):
    return  "Cadence: {0}  Gear: {1}  Speed: {2}".format(self._cadence, 
                                                         self._gear, self._speed)
```

That code tried to convert `self._cadence` to a string and `self._cadence` is `self` because of the previous error, so it continues in an endless recursion (until the recursion exception).

---

Note that `super()` takes two forms: with arguments and without arguments, so there are two correct ways to fix the code.

The Python 3 way (without arguments):

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

The old Python 2 way, which is more explicit:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(MountainBike, self).__init__()
```

Both do the same, i.e. they give you the bound `__init__` method which already has the implicit `self`.

See also here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super

Comment: So, either way, with or without arguments, passing `self` isn't necessary, correct?

Comment: @Sveta Exactly. Don't pass `self`.