# Value given when variable is empty

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I had the following `Player` base class:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Player(ABC):

    def __init__(self, name, player_type):
        self.name = name
        self.player_type = player_type
```

`Wizard`:

```
from Player import Player

class Wizard(Player):

    def __init__(self, name, player_type = "Wizard"):
        super().__init__(self,name)
```

`Main`:

```
from Player import Player
from Wizard import Wizard


def main():

    gandalf = Wizard("Gandalf")
    print(gandalf.name)

    # Will print gandalf because the parameter assignment was shifted
    # because self was passed from the child to base class.
    print(gandalf.player_type)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm aware from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437465/declaring-subclass-without-passing-self), you shouldn't pass `self` from the subclass to the base class. That being said, suppose you made the mistake of doing so, the line `print(gandalf.name)` prints `<Wizard.Wizard object at 0x049F20B0>` because `name` was never assigned but what exactly does this value mean?

Comment: It means you assigned the `self` into `name`...

Comment: @StephenRauch - Where does it come from? I understand why it prints that value, but how did come up with that value?

Comment: Your call to `super().__init__(self,name)` in `Wizard.__init__()` would fail because you need to pass `player_type` as well.

Comment: It's the string representation of the object itself: the result of `repr(gandalf)`.

Comment: @AGNGazer - The code will compile and run because I'm looking at it right now, however, if you attempt to print the `name` that value will be printed for the reason I specified above, but I want to understand where that value came from

Comment: That is the default string representation inherited from `object`. So try `print(gandalf)`. Realize, the `Wizard` object carries a reference to itself.

Comment: @AGNGazer this code would indeed work. The method expects three arguments and is being passed three arguments. The fact that two of them are `self` is irrelevant.

Comment: @AGNGazer - You shouldn't pass `self` from the child class to the base class, doing so can throw the parameter assignments off. The cod will compile and run

Comment: @Sveta it is hard to understand your question. You are passing `self` in the argument for `name`, so that is the value that is assigned; what is confusing to you?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Right, it's only until you print the `name` that you realize there was an error.

Comment: Well... Going to eat my hat... You are right... I missed `self`!

Comment: @DanielRoseman - I want to know how that value was generated. What about the Python environment made it go, I'll assign that value when `self` is pass from child to base when it expected another parameter.

Comment: @chepner explained this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50572602/value-given-when-variable-is-empty#comment88154878_50572602. When you `print(gandalf.name)`, `name` is an object that is being converted to a string for the purpose of printing using `repr(name)`.

Comment: Note, the variable is not empty. Such a thing doesn't really exist in Python.

Answer (score 2):

`super()` does not return a class; it returns a proxy object, so `super().__init__(self, name)` behaves much the same as `foo.__init__(self, name)`, where `foo` is a "real" instance of `Wizard`. That being the case, the first parameter `self` of the call to `Player.__init__` has already been assigned, so your *explicit* `self` is assigned to the *next* parameter, `name`, and your second argument `name` is assigned to the third parameter `player_type`.

Put another way, with `Player` being the next class in the MRO, `super().__init__(self, name)` is the same as `Player.__init__(self, self, name)`.

Put yet another way, `super().__init__` is a bound method, and so the `__init__` function's first parameter `self` has already been supplied.

Comment: So, I was correct in stating that it shifted the parameter assignments?

Comment: Yes, but that's normal for *any* bound method, just like `gandalf = Wizard("Gandalf")` results in an implicit call to `Wizard.__init__(gandalf, "Gandalf")`

Comment: In other words, don't pass `self`, that's done for you automatically, correct?

Comment: You can clean up the edit I made, but keep the comment about the `repr(gandalf)` because that's the real answer to my question, and I'll give you the checkmark.